# replicate presence from one ejabbered server to a differrent ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, user-presence

We have a stand-alone server that we can not get under the hood of. (if we could be roo, this would be solved already, but we cant) It has the presence (ie: phone, idle, away, vacation, custom, etc) for 2 dozen users.  Let's call this Server A. Let's consider this the server of record (ie: the presence it keeps for each user is correct).

Now, we have our own ejabberd (lets call it server B) running with the same 2 dozen users on it, as well as another 2 dozen users on it, who are not on server A.  Everyone uses server B for daily IM with everyone.

Our goal is to replicate the the presence of the 2 dozen users on Server A on to server B.

The use case would be this, user on server A changes presence to "away", this would be pushed on to server B were it would change that person from "available" to "away". Likewise, it would push the presence of "on phone" to server B where it would say that Tim in "on phone".

How can I do this?

Can I "pull" the presence every 60 seconds for each of the users & then (only if there is a change) "push" it in to server B? Can I use something like **mod_rest** or **mod_xmlrpc** write the presence to server B?

I will post my results here for all to benefit from once we're done in a few weeks so as to benefit the community.

Comment: Synchronize presence is not precise enough. You can indeed broadcast packets, but that will not give you the associated session. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @Mickaël  Thanks for the clarifying question. I hope this helps: user "1000" on server A changes status to "lunch". That same person is also user "thomas", on server B, and his presence changes to "lunch". User 1000 returns from lunch and on server changes status to "available" and user "thomas" on server B changes to "available".  Thanks so much.